# smartgwt - problem with labels

Tags: smartgwt

Over one month ago, I posted the following problem at http://forums.smartclient.com/index.php but nobody answered:

I use the following code from showcase:

```
public void onModuleLoad() {  

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas();  

            DragLabel dragTranslucent = new DragLabel("Translucent", 50);  
            dragTranslucent.setDragAppearance(DragAppearance.TARGET);  
            dragTranslucent.setDragOpacity(60);  
            canvas.addChild(dragTranslucent);  

            DragLabel dragShadow = new DragLabel("Shadow", 200);  
            dragShadow.setDragAppearance(DragAppearance.TARGET);  
            dragShadow.setShowDragShadow(true);  
            //TODO: dragShadow.setDragShadowDepth(8);  
            canvas.addChild(dragShadow);  

            DragLabel dragOutline = new DragLabel("Outline", 350);  
            dragOutline.setLeft(350);        
            dragOutline.setDragAppearance(DragAppearance.OUTLINE);  
            canvas.addChild(dragOutline);  

            canvas.draw();  
        }  

        public static class DragLabel extends Label {  
            public DragLabel(String contents, int left) {  
                setTop(50);  
                setLeft(left);  
                setContents(contents);  
                setAlign(Alignment.CENTER);  
                setPadding(4);  
                setShowEdges(true);  
                setBackgroundColor("#EEEEEE");  
                setKeepInParentRect(true);  
                setCanDragReposition(true);      
            }  
}
```

And this is the result (sorry for links, but I don't have any reputation points):

```
i47.tinypic.com/9rsqae.jpg
```

However, I should get something like this (it's from showcase):

```
i49.tinypic.com/11l670p.jpg
```

The problem concerns firefox and chrome. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by put `<!doctype html>` from html file in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking aroung Drag Objects and came across this.

It might be a strange but when i tasted it i got below link's result.

i49.tinypic.com/11l670p.jpg